# How to separate 2 div boxes in html/css?

Tags: html, css, frontend, mobile-website

Iam trying to make my first portfolio site and I've watch some tutorials on how to make a card thing that when you hover over will flip and show some information. However when i go to add another card of the exact same type it just sits directly on top of the old one and wont move. How can i get it so the 4 cards i made will show up in a 2 x 2dimension, so like below:

1stcard⠀⠀2ndcard

3rdcard⠀⠀4thcard

and not directly on top, while also keeping it mobile friendly? Thanks alot.

HTML

```
    <div class="card middle">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="sql.png" alt="sql">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="back-content middle">
                <h2>SQL</h2>
                <span>Database Query Tool</span>
                <div class="sm">
                    <p>SQL (STRUCTURED QUERY LANGUAGE). SQL LETS YOU ACCESS AND MANIPULATE DATABASES.
                            A QUERY LANGUAGE IS A KIND OF PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE THAT'S DESIGNED TO FACILITATE
                            RETRIEVING SPECIFIC INFORMATION FROM DATABASES, AND THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT SQL DOES.
                            I HAVE EXPERIENCE USING MYSQL AND SSMS (SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO).</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card middle">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="csharp.png" alt="sql">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="back-content middle">
                <h2>SQL</h2>
                <span>Database Query Tool</span>
                <div class="sm">
                    <p>SQL (STRUCTURED QUERY LANGUAGE). SQL LETS YOU ACCESS AND MANIPULATE DATABASES.
                            A QUERY LANGUAGE IS A KIND OF PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE THAT'S DESIGNED TO FACILITATE
                            RETRIEVING SPECIFIC INFORMATION FROM DATABASES, AND THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT SQL DOES.
                            I HAVE EXPERIENCE USING MYSQL AND SSMS (SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO).</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}

.front, .back{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform .6s linear;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
    border-radius: 2%;
}

.front img {
    height: 55%;
    width: 80%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 95px;
}

.front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
    background: #ffff;
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.back-content {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.sm {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.sm p {
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.card:hover > .front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card:hover > .back {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: By using transforms and stuff, you are giving yourself a difficult start :P. I'd advise you to read a nice introduction like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction. First make sure you really understand the concepts behind the `display` and `position` properties. Then try to start small, e.g. some text blocks next to each other. Once you understand the basics, go bigger and create those cards!

Comment: Ok thanks, however i kind of need a answer now as its quite urgent, just struggling to get it to not overlap

Comment: Hi @ericbailey101 - this question is still open. If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your `.middle` class to have a `position: relative` and i also wrapped the entire thing (both cards) into a new container with a `display: flex`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.middle {
    position: relative;
}

.card {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}

.front, .back{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform .6s linear;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
    border-radius: 2%;
}

.front img {
    height: 55%;
    width: 80%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 95px;
}

.front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
    background: #ffff;
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.back-content {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.sm {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.sm p {
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.card:hover > .front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card:hover > .back {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" class="css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card middle">
            <div class="front">
                <img src="sql.png" alt="sql">
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div class="back-content middle">
                    <h2>SQL</h2>
                    <span>Database Query Tool</span>
                    <div class="sm">
                        <p>SQL (STRUCTURED QUERY LANGUAGE). SQL LETS YOU ACCESS AND MANIPULATE DATABASES.
                                A QUERY LANGUAGE IS A KIND OF PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE THAT'S DESIGNED TO FACILITATE
                                RETRIEVING SPECIFIC INFORMATION FROM DATABASES, AND THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT SQL DOES.
                                I HAVE EXPERIENCE USING MYSQL AND SSMS (SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO).</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card middle">
            <div class="front">
                <img src="csharp.png" alt="sql">
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <div class="back-content middle">
                    <h2>SQL</h2>
                    <span>Database Query Tool</span>
                    <div class="sm">
                        <p>SQL (STRUCTURED QUERY LANGUAGE). SQL LETS YOU ACCESS AND MANIPULATE DATABASES.
                                A QUERY LANGUAGE IS A KIND OF PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE THAT'S DESIGNED TO FACILITATE
                                RETRIEVING SPECIFIC INFORMATION FROM DATABASES, AND THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT SQL DOES.
                                I HAVE EXPERIENCE USING MYSQL AND SSMS (SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO).</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks however for me the first card is like getting cut off at the top of the screen

Comment: @ericbailey101 you're right. try it again.

Comment: right yeah thanks its wokr now!, one last help please, so how can we get it so be in like a 2x2 confirguration so if i added 2 more cards , 4 in total. How can i get it so there is 2 cardson top then 2 cards on bottom, is it with grids?

Comment: @ericbailey101 yeah you can use grids too. See the other guys answer @cssyphus. He's got the grid in the ```.wrapper``` class.

Comment: yeah i manged to get it to be a in the middle and like one after another by adding this code to .container    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;    However its not going into a 2x2 manner its just 1 by 1

Comment: @ericbailey101 it's working for me. In your ```.container``` just put the ```display: grid;``` and ```grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;``` and remove everything else.

Comment: Yeah that works but dontyou get like a big gap between the 2 oppposite cards, and also its all pushing to the left hand side

Comment: @ericbailey101 You can change ```grid-template-columns``` to read ```1fr 2fr``` fr is a fraction of available space. While this brings it closer together, it might not be suitable to what you're trying to achieve overall. But test it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with CSS Grid or Flexbox. Just adding these two lines of CSS Grid do pretty much what you want, but watch a few tutorials and you'll be a maven.

```
.wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.middle {
    position: relative;
}
.card {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
}

.front, .back{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform .6s linear;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
    border-radius: 2%;
}

.front img {
    height: 55%;
    width: 80%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 95px;
}

.wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
}
.front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
    background: #ffff;
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.back-content {
    margin-top:50px;
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.sm {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.sm p {
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.card:hover > .front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card:hover > .back {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card middle">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/400" alt="sql">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="back-content middle">
                <h2>SQL</h2>
                <span>Database Query Tool</span>
                <div class="sm">
                    <p>SQL (STRUCTURED QUERY LANGUAGE). SQL LETS YOU ACCESS AND MANIPULATE DATABASES.
                            A QUERY LANGUAGE IS A KIND OF PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE THAT'S DESIGNED TO FACILITATE
                            RETRIEVING SPECIFIC INFORMATION FROM DATABASES, AND THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT SQL DOES.
                            I HAVE EXPERIENCE USING MYSQL AND SSMS (SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO).</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card middle">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/350" alt="sql">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="back-content middle">
                <h2>CATS</h2>
                <span>Catatonic Animals That Sleep</span>
                <div class="sm">
                    <p>DOGS HAVE FAMILY, CATS HAVE STAFF.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**References:**

[CSS Grid Tutorial - TheNetNinja](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7tLPhnA06w)

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/understanding-css-grid-container/